# Special characters to be used in subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess

In subprocess module in python,

```
 subprocess.Popen(
            (
                "git",
                "add",
                "-A",
                "&&",
                "git",
                "commit",
                "-m",
                commit_message
            ),
            cwd=path,
        )
```

does not work.
However if I split it into

```
 subprocess.Popen(( "git", "add","-A") , cwd=path)
```

and

```
subprocess.Popen(( "git", "commit","-m" , "yeah") , cwd=path)
```

it works. How do I insert "&&" in the middle? Thanks.

Comment: The various `subprocess` functions run *a single command*.  If you put a `&&` in the middle, it would simply be another parameter to that one command.  You do have the option of using `shell=True`, in which case the command that gets run is a shell; that shell is capable of interpreting an arbitrarily-complicated command line, including multiple commands and redirections.  Note that in this case, the command line should be provided as a single string, splitting it into a list is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` logical operator is something that the shell (e.g., bash) understands.  However, you're executing git which doesn't understand what `&&` means.  Explained another way, you're entering the arguments as if you were typing them into a terminal.  `subprocess.Popen` doesn't invoke the shell by default and instead invokes the `exec` system call with the specified arguments.  So, you're telling it to run `git` with the arguments `add`, `-A` (so far, so good), `&&` (git doesn't understand this), `git`, `-m`, and `yeah`.

To execute this as a shell command, you need to add `shell=True` to `subprocess.Popen`.  Once you do that, you can just type out the command you want as a single string:

```py
subprocess.Popen('git add -A && git commit -m', shell=true, cwd=path)
```

Comment: You bet me by 4 seconds!

Comment: Mavis-Beacon strikes again!

Answer (score 1):

Only a shell can interpet `&&`, it's not program or an argument

You can pass `shell=True` to  `subprocess.Popen` to run your command in a mini-shell like environment, see [docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-bin-sh-shell-command-substitution)